# Matrix multiplied by its Inverse doesn't return Identymatrix (but the other way around does)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So, I'm just figuring things out and can't wrap my head around the fact that the following code doesn't give me back an Identymatrix.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[2,3,5],[1,2,1],[4,6,3]])
bm = np.asmatrix(b)
print(bm)

c = np.linalg.inv(bm)
cm = np.asmatrix(c)
print(cm)

bm*cm
```

What baffles me is that

```
cm*bm
```

gives back the identymatrix. But why? For matrix multiplication the opposite had to be true

```
A*A^(-1) = I
```

Where A is bm and A^(-1) is cm.

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't give you back the identity matrix? I ran yourccode and tried both multiplications, `bm * cm` as well as `cm * bm` and get the identity matrix in both cases (with a tiny bit of floating point error in one case).

Comment: Well, I'm not experienced enough to recognize a floating point error as such, or to be more precise: I didn't expect python to calculate in such an imprecise way.

Comment: When asking questions like this, displaying the results that both you is polite.  While it's easy to recreate your problem, as shown in the answers, readers like to see the numbers that bother you.  The issue of floating point precision comes up often, and I wouldn't be surprised if this gets closed as a duplicate soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [756]: b = np.array([[2,3,5],[1,2,1],[4,6,3]])
In [757]: b
Out[757]: 
array([[2, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [4, 6, 3]])
```

Sticking with the `np.array` (`np.matrix` use is discouraged these days)

```
In [758]: c = np.linalg.inv(b)
In [759]: c
Out[759]: 
array([[ 0.        , -3.        ,  1.        ],
       [-0.14285714,  2.        , -0.42857143],
       [ 0.28571429,  0.        , -0.14285714]])
```

Note that the values are floats, which even with `float64` have limited precision.

Matrix multiplication of the two.  (`@` is matrix multiplication for both `ndarray` and `np.matrix`)

```
In [760]: b@c
Out[760]: 
array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-17],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
In [761]: np.allclose(b@c,np.eye(3))
Out[761]: True
```

`allclose` is recommended when testing equality with floats.  It allows for differences like `-5e-17`.

In `sympy` which uses symbols, algebra, and rationals (fractions):

```
In [38]: B = Matrix([[2,3,5],[1,2,1],[4,6,3]])

In [39]: B
Out[39]: 
⎡2  3  5⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢1  2  1⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣4  6  3⎦

In [40]: B.inv()
Out[40]: 
⎡ 0    -3   1  ⎤
⎢              ⎥
⎢-1/7  2   -3/7⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎣2/7   0   -1/7⎦

In [41]: B * B.inv()
Out[41]: 
⎡1  0  0⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢0  1  0⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣0  0  1⎦
```

Note those `1/7` fractions.  Scaling the float inverse:

```
In [762]: c*7
Out[762]: 
array([[  0., -21.,   7.],
       [ -1.,  14.,  -3.],
       [  2.,   0.,  -1.]])
```

And doing integer matrix multiplication:

```
In [765]: b@((c*7).astype(int))
Out[765]: 
array([[7, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 7]])
```

We can scale that back to 1:

```
In [767]: b@((c*7).astype(int))/7
Out[767]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

But if we scale before the multiplication:

```
In [768]: b@((c*7).astype(int)/7)
Out[768]: 
array([[1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.22044605e-16],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 5.55111512e-17],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

Answer (score 2):

A*A^(-1) = I
and
A^(-1)*A = I

should both be true.

I get somethin like this for the first multiplication:

```
[ 1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-17],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-17],
        [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Seems to be a numeric problem, but -5*10^-17 is preatty close to 0, so if you were to round your results, you would get I.

By the way, you dont need to convert c to a Matrix as it allready is.

Comment: "should both be true."
Are you sure about that? Because in matrix multiplication the rule is A\*B =/= B\*A.

Comment: yes but with inverse Matrix it works both ways: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxinvr2.htm